# Elliptic Curve Cryptography with Python on Windows

Tags: windows, python, encryption

I'm looking for a way to generate keys for asymmetric cryptography via elliptic curves in Python, but all packages I was able to find only support Unix systems. Does anyone know a package that works on Windows?